# How to add HTML tag in Drupal block ?

Tags: 7, blocks, theming

I would appreciate your help in my problem with html tagging or css class in blocks.

I've tried Field Formatter Class and Field Formatter CSS Class modules, but with those I only could add class to Article, Basic page and own types, which doesn't help me as I don't want to add Read more or RSS. When I definied my new content type, I didn't check the RSS box and I did check the full content box, but stil...

So, is there any module to add CSS class or HTML tag to a block. Different tags, of course for every block.

No PHP please.

Thanks,
cs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Block class](http://drupal.org/project/block_class) module which adds a field to each block where a class can be added.

Block Class allows users to add classes to any block through the block's configuration interface. By adding a very short snippet of PHP to a theme's block.tpl.php file, classes can be added to the parent `<div class="block ...">` element of a block.

Comment: Super cool, tahnk you! (:

Answer (score 0):

1. There is a method to add **class** to the **BLOCK-VIEW**(view in which results of the view would be displayed in a block)
2. In the Advanced setting tab,which is located near the block settings tab,
   **second last property is to add a css class**.

3.**save the settings and changes** you have made,and now you are done.
Your block now has a individual css class.